Check function invokable from std::variant
I am implementing Observator pattern with variadic template.
Subject class has parameter as subscibers and store them in std::vector<std::variant>. In function notify I am using std::visit to call function onMessage to notify all subscibers.
template<typename...Args>
class SubjectBase {
    using ArgsType = std::variant<Args*...>;
    std::vector<ArgsType> subscribers_;
public:

    SubjectBase(Args*... args): subscribers_{args...} {}

    template<typename Msg>
    auto notify(const Msg& msg) {
        for(auto subscriber: subscribers_) {
            std::visit([msg](const auto& x) {                    
                    x->onMessage(msg);                    
            }, subscriber);
        }
    }
private:
};

Subscriber class has parameter as Message Type which it would like to receive (for example, SubscriberOne get message Foo, Bar, but SubscriberTwo get only message Foo )
struct Foo {};
struct Bar {};

template<typename ...Args>
class SubscriberBase {
public:
    auto onMessage(const auto& msg);
};

class SubscriberOne: public SubscriberBase<Foo, Bar> {
public:
    auto onMessage(const Foo& foo) {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }

    auto onMessage(const Bar& foo) {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

class SubscriberTwo: public SubscriberBase<Foo> {
public:
    auto onMessage(const Foo& foo) {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

My main function, for example.
int main() {
   
    SubscriberOne one;
    SubscriberTwo two;

    SubjectBase<SubscriberOne, SubscriberTwo> subjectOne(&one, &two);
    SubjectBase<SubscriberOne> subjectTwo(&one);

    Foo foo;
    Bar bar;
    subjectOne.notify(foo);
    // subjectOne.notify(bar); --> // this line error due to SubcriberTwo has no onMessage(Bar&)

    return 0;
}

Can we check function is invokable in std::visit? For example, use if constexpr to check type in the variant.
Edit
I update version of CRTP for SubsciberBase as @alager's suggestion.
https://godbolt.org/z/cnj5vnqv5

Observator pattern can be implemented with std::function now.

SubjectBase doesn't have to erase/hide type inside a std::variant, using std::tuple might be used (your issue to call conditionally is still there, and solution also apply to it).

In fact, it seems strange to fix subscribers of SubjectBase at compilation. the pattern allows dynamic subscriptions.

My guess is you're on C++20. If so, you can use concepts to check if a given type has onMessage function (OK, member but also static, I used simplified approach here) callable with a given type.
If you're using some older standard, this is probably also doable but in a bit more convoluted manner.

template<typename T, typename MSG>
concept HasMessageHandler = requires(T obj, const MSG& msg) {
    { obj.onMessage(msg) } ;
};

template<typename...Args>
class SubjectBase {
    using ArgsType = std::variant<Args*...>;
    std::vector<ArgsType> subscribers_;
public:

    SubjectBase(Args*... args): subscribers_{args...} {}

    template<typename Msg>
    auto notify(const Msg& msg) {
        for(auto subscriber: subscribers_) {
            std::visit([msg](const auto& x) {
                using ObjType = std::remove_pointer_t<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(x)>>;
                // uncomment line below to see how it fails
                // static_assert(HasMessageHandler<ObjType, decltype(msg)>); 
                if constexpr(HasMessageHandler<ObjType, decltype(msg)> ) {
                                   
                    x->onMessage(msg);                    
                }
            }, subscriber);
        }
    }
private:
};

Also, didn't you have some sort of CRTP in mind?
Because currently SubscriberBase is completely unnecessary.
Demo:
https://godbolt.org/z/87jcsejTb
With SubscriberBase gotten rid of:
https://godbolt.org/z/c4cMajzrP

Great answer.  I used standard C++23. I forgot the concept . Thanks.
